# Elegant way to return different variables based on input flags

Tags: python, return

I have a function that opens a text file, parses a bunch of data and returns the numeric results in an array. Now I also want this function to do some optional calculations on the fly and return those values if I need them.

For a single flag this is fairly clean, e.g.:

```
def read_data(file_name, calc_a=False):
    # do normal parsing and store data in 'xyz'
    if calc_a:
        # calc some other stuff and store in 'a'
        return xyz, a
    else:
        return xyz
```

Now if I want to have multiple optional flags things quickly become messy, e.g.:

```
def read_data(file_name, calc_a=False, calc_b=False):
    # do normal parsing and store data in 'xyz'
    if calc_a:
        # calc some other stuff and store in 'a'
    if calc_b:
        # calc some other stuff and store in 'b'

    if calc_a and calc_b:
        return xyz, a, b
    elif calc_a:
        return xyz, a
    elif calc_b:
        return xyz, b
    else:
        return xyz
```

Is there a cleaner way to handle this situation?

Comment: Having a function that returns different amounts of stuff like that is inherently somewhat awkward.  Instead, why don't you just always return some data structure that contains slots for each piece of info, where some might be None if you didn't calculate that info.  (e.g., return a list where some elements might be None).

Comment: Having a function that chooses what calculations to run based on arguments is a lot like just having a class with methods.

Comment: Aside: `def` is a Python keyword, and so can't be used as a name..

Comment: It might help me to understand why you need to store the various results in such arbitrary variable names.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't just return a list of stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def read_data(file_name, *extras):
    # Read the data from file_name, organizing in a dict,
    # using the key names that your caller will pass into the function.
    # In this example, we have the main data that will always be
    # returned, plus optional data stored under keys a, b, c, d.
    data = dict(_main = 'MAIN', a = 'AA', b = 'BB', c = 'CC', d = 'DD')

    # Return a tuple, list, or even dict of that data.
    ks = sorted(data.keys())
    return tuple(data[k] for k in ks if k in extras or k == '_main')

# Caller requests the optional data they want.
# This example shows the caller passing a list of optional data keys.
# You could also have them pass keyword args instead.
wanted = 'a b d'.split()
print read_data('data_file', *wanted)  # ('MAIN', 'AA', 'BB', 'DD')
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like:

```
ret = (xyz,)
if calc_a:
    ret += (abc,)
if calc_b:
    ret += (def,)

return ret[0] if len(ret) == 1 else ret
```

If you're doing this with a lot of variables, consider using a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or a dict to return subsets for ease of use. For the namedtuple, that'd look something like:

```
fields = ['regular_ans']
ret = [xyz]

if calc_a:
    fields.append('a')
    ret.append(abc)
if calc_b:
    fields.append('b')
    ret.append(def)

if len(ret) == 1:
    return ret[0]
return namedtuple('ResultType', fields)(*ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of argument unpacking?

http://hangar.runway7.net/python/packing-unpacking-arguments

Comment: I don't see how this helps in this case...?

Answer (score 0):

And now for something completely excessive...

```
import operator

pMap = {
  (False, False): ('foo',),
  (False, True): ('foo', 'bar'),
  (True, False): ('foo', 'bar'),
  (True, True): ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
}

def func(var, pred1=False, pred2=False):
  # calculations go here
  return operator.itemgetter(*pMap[bool(pred1), bool(pred2)])(dict(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3))

print func(None)
print func(None, pred2=True)
print func(None, True, True)
```

Comment: Let's not crack under pressure.

Comment: This makes me think of most of the LINQ I've seen :(

Answer (score 0):

I might use a class with chainable methods.

```
class DataReader(object):
  abc = None
  deef = None
  def __init__(self, file_name):
    self.xyz = self.normal_parsing(file_name)
  def calc_a(self):
    self.abc = some_calculation(self.xyz)
    return self
  def calc_b(self):
    self.deef = othr_calculation(self.xyz)
    return self
```

Then you can do something like:

```
dr = DataReader("watfile").calc_a().calc_b()
# Now you have access to dr.xyz, dr.abc and dr.deef.
# If you don't run all the methods, some of those would be None
```

(To be completely honest, I probably *wouldn't* do this. I would probably reformulate the problem so that my functions returned useful values. But I don't know your constraints.)